# SignalR Support in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, signalr

I want to run SignalR application in IE. Is SignalR support in IE. If it doesn't is there anyway I can get it working in IE. **Which versions of IE the SignalR doesn't support.**

Comment: Yes it does. Do you have a more specific question to ask.

Comment: which versions of IE, the signalr doesn't support

Comment: We don't support IE < 8. Even though older versions may work, we don't  actively test them or fix bugs in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't support IE < 8. Even though older versions may work, we don't actively test them or fix bugs in them